# Are most browsers in 2016 "intelligent" enough to do their own lazy loading of images?

Tags: browser, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

If you are implementing a raster-images heavy website, do you still need to actively pursue a lazy loading strategy or are most browsers capable of deciding what images are in or near the viewport?

In short: do I need to invest time in finding "the best, latest, and greatest" lazy loading js-lib on github or can I relax?

In the greater scheme of things: is it better to lazy load whole portions of the page in question, or is nitpicking images the best way forward or is none of it needed as per the reason given in the question heading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK current browsers do not really automatically do "lazy loading" for images that are outside the viewport. (I don't really have deep knowledge on browser mechanism) Thus for my own project, I opt to use the current popular lazy loading javascript library, http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

It is **extremely easy** to use and definitely **not time consuming**. You can roughly get the idea of how to implement it by reading their documentation.

Logically this is suitable for your images-heavy site. It only loads images in the viewport so it will reduce the loading time of your site.

Hope this helps.